# Excel Macro Run Time Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Tags: excel, vba

I’m getting difficult to solve the macro issue for making pivot table.

When I run the macro, i get the error [run time error 5] and if I click debug, i see the codes as below with the yellow highlighted “Selection.AutoFilter”.

Can I please get help to solve this issue?

```
Sub DailyInvoiceReport()
    
    '
    
    ' DailyInvoiceReport Macro
    
    '
    
    '
    
    Columns("K:N").Select
    
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = FALSE
    
    Range("K:K,M:M").Select
    
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = TRUE
    
    Cells.Select
    
    Range("B1").Activate
    
    Selection.Copy
    
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                           
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Range("X1").FormulaR1C1 = _
                              
    "=IF(OR(LEFT(RC[-22],2)=""94"",LEFT(RC[-22],2)=""96""),RC[-10]*-1,RC[-10])"
    
    Range("X1").Select
    
    Selection.Copy
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10).Range("A1").Select
    
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Range("A1").Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    Columns("X:X").Select
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = FALSE
    
    Selection.Copy
    
    Columns("N:N").Select
    
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                           
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Columns("X:X").Select
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = FALSE
    
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    
    Range("B1").Select
    
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Activate
    
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
    Range("B1").Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    
    Selection.Copy
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Daily Invoice"
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Pivot"
    
    Worksheets("Daily Invoice").Activate
    
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    Rows("1:1").Select
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = FALSE
    
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    
    Range("A1") = "Invoice"
    
    Range("B1") = "PO#"
    
    Range("C1") = "Billing creation date"
    
    Range("D1") = "Customer party#"
    
    Range("E1") = "Customer Party Name"
    
    Range("F1") = "Method of Delivery"
    
    Range("G1") = "Method of Delivery 2"
    
    Range("H1") = "Term"
    
    Range("I1") = "Amount"
    
    Range("J1") = "Success"
    
    Range("K1") = "Pending"
    
    Range("L1") = "Success Amount"
    
    Range("M1") = "Pending Amount"
    
    Range("A1").Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    
    Selection.AutoFilter
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$500").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=RGB(146, _
                                                
    208, 80), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    
    Range("J2").Select
    
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    
    Range("J2").Select
    
    Selection.Copy
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
    
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    Range("A1").Select
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = FALSE
    
    Selection.AutoFilter
    
    Range("K2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=1,0,1)"
    
    Range("L2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC[-2]=1,RC[-1]=0),RC[-3],0)"
    
    Range("M2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC[-3]=0,RC[-2]=1),RC[-4],0)"
    
    Range("K2").Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    
    Selection.Copy
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Range("A1").Select
    
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1:C1").Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Set DRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)
    
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
                                                              
    DRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
                                                              
    TableDestination:="Pivot!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion _
                                                              
    :=xlPivotTableVersion15
    
    Sheets("Pivot").Select
    
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Customer Party Name")
        
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        
        .Position = 1
        
    End With
    
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Method of Delivery")
        
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        
        .Position = 2
        
    End With
    
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Term")
        
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        
        .Position = 3
        
    End With
    
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Method of Delivery 2")
        
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        
        .Position = 1
        
    End With
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
                                                        
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Success"), "Sum of Success", xlSum
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
                                                        
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Pending"), "Sum of Pending", xlSum
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").CalculatedFields.Add "Total Invoice", _
                                                                
    "=Success +Pending", TRUE
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Total Invoice"). _
                                                              
    Orientation = xlDataField
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
                                                        
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Success Amount"), "Sum of Success Amount", xlSum
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
                                                        
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Pending Amount"), "Sum of Pending Amount", xlSum
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").CalculatedFields.Add "Total Amount", _
                                                                
    'Success Amount' +'Pending Amount'", True
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Total Amount").Orientation _
                                                              
    = xlDataField
    
    Rows("3:3").Select
    
    Selection.Replace What:="Sum of", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                      
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                      
    ReplaceFormat:=False
    
    Range("A3").Select
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").CompactLayoutRowHeader = "Customer"
    
    Range("B3:I3").Select
    
    With Selection
        
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        
        .WrapText = FALSE
        
        .Orientation = 0
        
        .AddIndent = FALSE
        
        .IndentLevel = 0
        
        .ShrinkToFit = FALSE
        
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        
        .MergeCells = FALSE
        
    End With
    
    Range("E4").Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    
    Range("D3").Select
    
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:C1").Select
    
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Invoice").Subtotals = Array _
                                                                              
    (False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("PO#").Subtotals = Array( _
                                                                          
    False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Billing creation date"). _
                                                                
    Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, _
                                                                
    False, False)
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Customer party#"). _
                                                                 
    Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, _
                                                                 
    False, False)
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Customer Party Name"). _
                                                                 
    Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, _
                                                                 
    False, False)
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Method of Delivery"). _
                                                               
    Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, _
                                                               
    False, False)
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Method of Delivery 2"). _
                                                               
    Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, _
                                                               
    False, False)
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Term").Subtotals = Array( _
                                                                           
    False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Amount").Subtotals = Array( _
                                                                             
    False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Success").Subtotals = Array _
                                                                              
    (False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Pending").Subtotals = Array _
                                                                              
    (False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Success Amount").Subtotals _
                                                                
    = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, FALSE _
                                                                
    )
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Pending Amount").Subtotals _
                                                                
    = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, FALSE _
                                                                
    )
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").ShowDrillIndicators = FALSE
    
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Tried to delete the highlighted section’Selection.AutoFilter’.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs on this line:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
```

You cannot go down when the selected cell is on the last line (1048576)